# How can I follow someone from my non-default account?

Tags: user-accounts, tweetdeck

In Tweetdeck I have two accounts; a default one and a secondary one. I have them both in separate columns.

However, when a person crops up in my non-default account column that I want to follow I can't seem to find a way to follow them from that account.

Hovering over the 'Follow' button brings up the tooltip saying 'From {@Account A}' but no way to switch to the other account.

[image: Tweetdeck screenshot]

Aside from opening up the link in my browser, signing into Twitter from my second account and then finding the user that way, can I do it directly from Tweetdeck?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the left of the follow button is an image of a head with a pull down menu. The second from the top option in the pull down menu is "follow from user accounts".  Select this option and a dialogue box appears with your various accounts with a follow button beside them. You can select whichever one you want to follow from.

Comment: Yup, good find there. I wonder if that's always been the case? I'd have thought I'd have noticed that option before, but it certainly is the way to do it it as of today.

Comment: Brilliant UI, this. /s (Thank you for the answer.)